# Changing dynamically the look of an android app

Tags: android, user-interface, themes

I do an android project for my university and we want that the looks of it changes depending on the location of the user.

For example if the user is near a sea area, it is pirate themed, with wooden buttons, ocean background and so on. 
If the user is near a mountain area, it is maybe viking themed. You get the idea.

My question is now: What is the best way of implementing something like this?

Thanks in advance for the answers :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use custom activity themes. With styles and (custom) theme attributes you can place all customizable styling in your theme. Although it's a bit cumbersome, you can change the theme at run time. A theme is applied when views are created, so you'd have to ensure that activities are recreated. You can provide a better experience if you handle that change manually.

Your layout typically looks something like this:

**Example of a typical layout**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/pirate_background">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/pirate_greeting"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/greeting"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:text="@string/pirate_greeting"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now if all those attributes named pirate_* should be changeable, you want to place those in your theme, so that changing the theme automatically changes those elements. The most basic approach is to define a theme attribute for every attribute that you want to customize. That would look like this:

**Layout with custom theme attributes**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="?attr/my_layout_background">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="?attr/my_image_src"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/greeting"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:text="?attr/my_greeting_text"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

That question mark ? indicates that you are referring to a themed attribute. You define those attributes in a resource file, usually named 'attrs.xml'.

**values/attrs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="my_layout_background" format="reference" />
    <attr name="my_image_src" format="reference" />
    <attr name="my_greeting_text" format="string" />
</resources>
```

These attributes will only work if your theme has defined a value for them. So whatever theme you have, ensure that it includes a definition for the attributes above.

**values/themes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyAppTheme" parent="[your base theme]">
        <item name="my_layout_background">@drawable/default_greeting</item>
        <item name="my_image_src">@drawable/default_greeting</item>
        <item name="my_greeting_text">@string/default_greeting</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyAppTheme.Pirates">
        <item name="my_layout_background">@drawable/pirate_background</item>
        <item name="my_image_src">@drawable/pirate_greeting</item>
        <item name="my_greeting_text">@string/pirate_greeting</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyAppTheme.China">
        <item name="my_layout_background">@drawable/china_background</item>
        <item name="my_image_src">@drawable/nihao</item>
        <item name="my_greeting_text">@string/nihao</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

For brevity I'm going to assume you know how to setup a theme (if you don't, learn it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)). Tip: in Android Studio's layout editor, you can specify a theme which allows you to preview your layout in different themes. Play around with it a little.

So far you've completed the easy part. We're going to change the configuration at runtime now, and that's the part that's not so easy. But if you follow my instructions it shouldn't be too hard. For a typical activity, views are created (or inflated) in the `setContentView(...)` method. Whatever the theme is at that time, will decide what the views look like. So if you want to change your theme programmatically, you should make sure you do it before `setContentView(...)` is called.

**Activity that sets a custom theme**

```
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(R.style.MyAppTheme_Pirates);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // ...
}
```

Most of the time you probably want to change the theme when the activity is already created. You can use the `recreate()` method for that, which will destroy the current activity and immediately create a new one. Of course, if you destroy the activity, you will lose any data it holds (such as the theme you want to change to). There's two ways of dealing with that:

1. When you determine a theme to apply, don't store this data in the activity, store it somewhere it doesn't disappear when an activity is destroyed.
2. Use `onSaveInstanceState()` in the activity, and store the theme there. If you do it that way you can restore this information when the new activity is created.

Which ever way you choose is up to you. Which is more suitable really depends on how you choose to structure your code. Whatever you choose, in the end your activity will have code like this:

**Activity that recreates itself to apply a new theme**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(ThemeStorage.getTheme());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void applyNewTheme(@StyleRes int themeResId) {
    ThemeStorage.setTheme(themeResId);
    recreate();
}
```

Now all you need to do is have some code that determines what theme to apply. This could be a background service that listens to location updates. If it determines that the app should change to a new theme, you just call `applyNewTheme` on some or all of the running activities. You can get a list of all the running activities by using the `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`. You register those callbacks in the Application class. Here's some code to make that easy.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private ActivityCollector mActivityCollector = new ActivityCollector();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
       registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(mActivityCollector.getCallbacks());
    }

    public ActivityCollector getActivityCollector() {
        return mActivityCollector;
    }
}

/**
 * Uses {@link android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks} to 
 * maintain a list of created activities.
 */
public class ActivityCollector {

    private List<Activity> mCreatedActivities = new ArrayList<>();
    private ActivityLifecycleCallbacks mLifecycleCallbacks = new ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            mCreatedActivities.add(activity);
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
            mCreatedActivities.remove(activity);
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {
        }
    };

    public List<Activity> getCreatedActivities() {
        return mCreatedActivities;
    }

    public ActivityLifecycleCallbacks getCallbacks() {
        return mLifecycleCallbacks;
    }
}
```

So, pass that `ActivityCollector` to the code that needs to apply themes to your activities, and you're all set.

Comment: Cool thanks :) We want to start developing very soon and if we could implement this from the get-go, it would be really great !

Comment: I am baffled how detailed your instructions are and I am really thankful for that!